# How to convert string into array?

Tags: magento2.2

I am getting the below mentioned string in my API response. How can I convert this into array?

```
 "product_options": "{\"info_buyRequest\":{\"qty\":1},\"giftcard_lifetime\":null,\"giftcard_is_redeemable\":0,\"giftcard_email_template\":null,\"giftcard_type\":null}"
```

> Vendor/CustomApi/Model/OrderHistory.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomApi\Model;

use Amos\CustomApi\Api\OrderHistoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class OrderHistory implements OrderHistoryInterface {

    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(CustomerFactory $customerFactory, CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository) {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function getOrderHistory($customerId, $direction, $pageSize, $currentPage) {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                    ->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id", array("eq" => $customerId));
            $CustomerResult = $customer->getData();
            $customerInfo = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
            $customerAttributeData = $customerInfo->__toArray();
            $VesselId = $customerAttributeData['custom_attributes']['customer_vessels']['value'];
            $customerData = $this->customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                            ->addAttributeToFilter("customer_vessels", array("eq" => $VesselId))
                            ->addAttributeToFilter("group_id", array("eq" => self::GROUP_ID))->load();
            $CustomerDataResult = $customerData->getData();
            $captinId = $CustomerDataResult[0]['entity_id'];
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $captinId)->setOrder('entity_id', $direction)->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($currentPage);
            $orderInfo = $order->getData();
//            print_r($orderInfo);die();
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $orderItemCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\Collection')
                    ->setOrder('entity_id', $direction);

            $orderItemCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    'sales_order', 'sales_order.entity_id=main_table.order_id', ['increment_id']
            )->where('sales_order.customer_id=?', $captinId);
            $orderResult = $orderItemCollection->getData();
            foreach ($orderInfo as $k => $v) {
                foreach ($orderResult as $k1 => $v1) {
                    if ($v1['order_id'] == $v['entity_id']) {
                        $orderInfo[$k]['product_details'][] = $v1;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(
            __('Invalid customer.')
            );
        }
        return json_decode($orderInfo);
    }

}
```

> Vendor/CustomApi/Api/OrderHistoryInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomApi\Api;


interface OrderHistoryInterface {
     CONST GROUP_ID = 5;
    /**
     * User can login and once logged in success, user will receive their information with order history.
     * @param int $customerId
     * @param string $direction
     * @param int $pageSize
     * @param int $currentPage
     * @return mixed Order History
     */
    public function getOrderHistory($customerId,$direction,$pageSize,$currentPage);
}
```

Comment: have you tried `json_decode` ?

Comment: I have tried this but getting error as following:

    "message": "Class mixed does not exist",
    "code": -1,

Comment: please share your code here, it should work with `json_decode`

Comment: I have added my code. Please check.

Comment: I am unable to find `json_decode` in your code

Comment: you can do it like suggested by Shoaib : `$result = json_decode($orderInfo);

            return $result;` and it will give array result.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have added json_decode in the code. Please check now.

Comment: try `return print_r($orderInfo);`

Comment: don't use json_decode on in return, this is already in array. just use `return $orderInfo;`

Comment: I have faced the same issue, Try this out....      

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($orderInfo);

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this below code where you want to convert to array :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
 */
protected $jsonHelper;

/**
 * [__construct description]
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data              $jsonHelper        [description]
 */
public function __construct(
    .......
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    .......
) {
    .......
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    .......
}

public function yourFunction() {
    $strToArr = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode('your data');
    print_r($strToArr);
}
```